Snowflake Notebook- How to run notebook parllalley
I am trying to run snowflake notebook paralley using python concurrent process- ThreadPoolExecutor
However the execution failing
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session
from snowflake.snowpark.exceptions import SnowparkSQLException
session = get_active_session()
def execute_copy_command_with_session(cmd):
    try:
        
        result = session.sql(cmd).collect()
        print("result is", result)
        return {"success": True, "result": result}
    except SnowparkSQLException as e:
        print(f"An error occurred during the copy operation: {e}")
        return {"success": False, "error": str(e)}

copy_list2 = ["""select count(*) from table1""",
             """select count(*) from table2""",
             """select count(*) from table3"""]

# Use ThreadPoolExecutor to execute copy commands in parallel
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(copy_list)) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(execute_copy_command_with_session, cmd) for cmd in copy_list2]
    
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        if result["success"]:
            print("Task succeeded:", result["result"])
        else:
            print("Task failed with error:", result["error"])

below is the error i am getting
No sessioncontext

is this the right approach to achieve parallel processing with in notebook?
